# VB6 debug cannot step into another project

Tags: debugging, com, vb6, step-into

I have a y.vbg with 3 projects in it.

x1.vbp *StartUp Project
x2.vbp
x3.vbp

x1.vbp reference x2.dll and x3.dll.  When I put a break point in x1.vbp and try to step into a function in x2, I cannot.

Any tips and tricks will help.

Comment: What are your compatibility levels for x2.dll and x3.dlls?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to vb6 so I don't know what compatibility levels are.

Answer (score 5):

The answer was in Naresh's question.  -Thanks Naresh.

I changed x2.vbp's component "Version Compatibility" to "Binary Compatibility and now I can step into and break points are hitting.  To do this, go to the project's property.